# Loading from pickled data causes database error with new saves

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, pickle

In order to save time moving data I pickled some models and dumped them to file.  I then reloaded them into another database using the same exact model.  The save worked fine and the objects kept their old id which is what I wanted.  However, when saving new objects I run into nextval errors.

Not being very adept with postgres, I'm not sure how to fix this so I can keep old records with their existing ID while being able to continue adding new data.

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are talking about the sequence that is being used for autoincrementing your id fields.

the easiest solution here would be in a "psql" shell:

```
select max(id)+1 from YOURAPP_YOURMODEL;
```

and use the value in this command:

```
alter sequence YOURAPP_YOURMODEL_id_seq restart with MAX_ID_FROM_PREV_STATEMENT;
```

that should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

There is actually a django command that prints out sequence reset SQL called [sqlsequencereset](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#sqlsequencereset-appname-appname).

```
$ python manage.py sqlsequencereset issues
BEGIN;
SELECT setval('"issues_project_id_seq"', coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "issues_project";
COMMIT;
```